# Iterating pattern (1-10 then 10-1) with only 1 loop

Tags: algorithm, c

I want to obtain the following output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

The code am running is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i=1,flag=0,lines=0;  //0 for forward, 1 for reverse
    while(i!=0 && lines<3){
        if(!flag){
            printf("%d ",i);
            if(i==10){
                flag=1;
                printf("\n");
                lines++;
            }
            else
                i++;
        }
        else if(flag){
            printf("%d ",i);
            if(i==1){
                lines++;
                flag=0;
                printf("\n");
            }
            else
                i--;
         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Am getting the desired output from the above code but not sure if it's an optimal code. Any other method/suggestion? Considering unlimited space but time complexity should be kept minimum.

**Condition:** Use only one loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any compelling reason for doing this in one loop, but it's certainly possible in a simpler way.  First, though let's look at some other aspects of the code.

### Declare one variable per line

Generally, it's better for readability if we declare just one variable per line instead of cramming them all together on a single line.

### Use more whitespace

Lines like this

```
while(i!=0 && lines<3){
```

Are rendered much more readable if we use more whitespace:

```
while (i != 0 && lines < 3) {
```

### Use braces consistently

I'd recommend using braces around the `else` clause statement, even though it isn't technically required.  In addition to making things more readable (there's that word again!) it helps to prevent bugs.

### Use better variable names

In the current code, `lines` is a good variable name because it suggests the purpose of the variable, but `flag` is not a very good name.  It would be better to make it `bool` and call it `reverse`.

### Use named constants

Named constants make it easier for readers of the program to understand what's being done and why.

### Simplify your code

Essentially, what the program is intended to do is make three traversals from 1 to 10 and back.  I'd write it like this:

```
int main(void) {
    const int lowerlimit = 1;
    const int upperlimit = 10;
    int i = lowerlimit; 
    int delta = +1;  // start counting up
    for (int traversals=3; traversals; ) {
        printf("%d ", i);
        i += delta;
        if (i > upperlimit || i < lowerlimit) {
            printf("\n");
            delta *= -1;   // change direction
            i += delta;    // come back in bounds
            --traversals;
        }
    }
}
```

### Omit `return 0`

When a C or C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no need to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.

**Note:** when I make this suggestion, it's almost invariably followed by one of two kinds of comments:  "I didn't know that." or "That's bad advice!"  My rationale is that it's safe and useful to rely on compiler behavior explicitly supported by the standard.  For C, since C99; see ISO/IEC 9899:1999 section 5.1.2.2.3:

> [...] a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument; reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0.

For C++, since the first standard in 1998; see ISO/IEC 14882:1998 section 3.6.1:

> If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;

All versions of both standards since then (C99 and C++98) have maintained the same idea.  We rely on automatically generated member functions in C++, and few people write explicit `return;` statements at the end of a `void` function.  Reasons against omitting seem to boil down to ["it looks weird"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581993/what-the-reasons-for-against-returning-0-from-main-in-iso-c/2582015#2582015).  If, like me, you're curious about the rationale for the change to the C standard [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394171/what-was-the-rationale-for-making-return-0-at-the-end-of-main-optional).  Also note that in the early 1990s this was considered "sloppy practice" because it was undefined behavior (although widely supported) at the time.

So I advocate omitting it; others disagree (often vehemently!)  In any case, if you encounter code that omits it, you'll know that it's explicitly supported by the standard and you'll know what it means.

Comment: Bit of a crusade going on against that `return 0` with almost 300 words about that every time it appears? I thought people usually recommend  making the code explicit and consistent to cause less confusion. Here, you recommend removing a line because it _can_ be removed in just that one case (but not in others, like `return 1` or returns from other functions). While at the same time, you disapprove of multiple variable declarations in one line (even though they are allowed), _and_ use a `+` in front of `1` in `int delta = +1;` (even though it's not at all required.)

Comment: @ilkkachu: There's no crusade.  I simply review code and provide comments and suggestions based on my knowledge and experience.  Those who read it can decide for themselves whether to apply some, all or none of it.

Comment: In the case of `int delta = +1;` it is written that way to emphasize that it's a signed variable that gets values of either `-1` or `+1`.  In all cases, the point is readability and consistency rather than saving keystrokes.